# Spring Boot and Cassandra failing in using a jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jar, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am porting an application to Spring Boot and Spring Cassandra. I have instantiated Cassandra Cluster. Previously my application was hosted over Tomcat (using Spring Data Cassandra) and I never faced any issue with the same Jar. Today when I have ported my application to Spring Boot, I am getting the below error when I try to access any methods from my JAR -

> 2017-01-20 14:38:16.017  INFO 6724 --- [           main]
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host
>   iacass302p.stress.ch3.s.com/10.235.91.41:9042 added 2017-01-20
>   14:38:16.017  INFO 6724 --- [           main]
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host
>   iacass301p.stress.ch3.s.com/10.235.91.40:9042 added 2017-01-20
>   14:38:16.017  INFO 6724 --- [           main]
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host
>   iacass303p.stress.ch3.s.com/10.235.91.42:9042 added 2017-01-20
>   14:38:16.017  INFO 6724 --- [           main]
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host
>   iacass402p.stress.ch4.s.com/10.236.67.50:9042 added 2017-01-20
>   14:38:16.017  INFO 6724 --- [           main]
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host
>   iacass401p.stress.ch4.s.com/10.236.66.83:9042 added 2017-01-20
>   14:38:16.017  INFO 6724 --- [           main]
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host
>   /10.236.67.51:9042 added 2017-01-20 14:38:17.646  INFO 6724 --- [
>   main] c.s.s.d.s.dao.impl.CacheBuilderDAOImpl   : CacheBuilderDAOImpl :
>   Inside method init keyspace:capacity columnfamily:freight_lane
>   2017-01-20 14:39:03.755  WARN 6724 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'deliveryCalendar3PLHandler':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'deliveryCalendar3PLProcessor'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'deliveryCalendar3PLProcessor':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'freightAreaStatusdDao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'freightArea_Dao': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'cassandraOperations'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=cassandraNewTemplate)}
>   2017-01-20 14:39:03.777  INFO 6724 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
>   2017-01-20 14:39:03.794  INFO 6724 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2017-01-20
>   14:39:03.900 ERROR 6724 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field cassandraOperations in
>   com.searshc.dce.persistence.DcePersistence.dao.impl.FreightAreaDaoImpl
>   required a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations' that
>   could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations' in your
>   configuration.

An extract of code in my JAR

```
 @Component
public class FreightAreaDaoImpl
  implements FreightAreaDao
{
  private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FreightAreaDaoImpl.class);
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("cassandraNewTemplate")
  private CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;
  private Session cassandraSession;
  PreparedStatement getFreightLaneStmt = null;

  public void initStatements()
  {
    if (this.cassandraOperations == null)
    {
      LOG.error("Cassandra not available");
    }
    else
    {
      LOG.error("FreightAreaDaoImpl:: Cassandra available: session initialized.");
      this.cassandraSession = this.cassandraOperations.getSession();

      this.getFreightLaneStmt = this.cassandraSession.prepare("select * from capacity.freight_area where geocode_no = ? ");
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the exception message? It's saying that there's no `CassandraOperations` bean with the `cassandraNewTemplate` qualifier. Either remove the qualifier or provide a `CassandraOperations` bean with the `cassandraNewTemplate` qualifier.

Comment: If that is the problem, it should have been failing prior to migrating to Spring Boot as well. This jar was working fine with spring boot cassandra prior to this.